# React shouldComponentUpdate doesn't detect array length change?

Tags: reactjs

When Changing the length of an array passed through props, the 'shouldComponentUpdate' function can't detect the array length change. 
I know that 'shouldComponentUpdate' can't detect changes in nested objects properties, but this is a simple array length!! is this a bug in React??

https://jsfiddle.net/ashraffayad/cLz1q8sv/

```
var ArrTest = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div >{this.props.arr}< /div>;
  },
  shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps) {
    console.log(this.props.arr.length, nextProps.arr.length); // same length !!!
    return true;
  }
});

// - - - - app component
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      arr: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    return <ArrTest arr={ this.state.arr } />;
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.state.arr.push(7);
      self.setState(self.state);
    }, 2000);
  }

});

ReactDOM.render( < App /> ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a bug in React, it's an issue with your code.
You should never modify `this.state` values directly.

Try this:

```
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.setState({arr: self.state.arr.concat([7])});
    }, 2000);
  }
```

It works. Because React doesn't clone props as it passes them down, and so changes to an array get reflect on all of its references.

I suggest you read more about immutability in Javascript.

In short, never do `this.state.[anything].push/pop/shift/unshift()`, never.
Do something like this instead:

```
var arr = this.state.arr.slice(); // Create a copy of the array
arr.push(2); // do whatever you want to do
this.setState({ arr: arr }); // pass changes to React
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because you have two references (`this.props.arr`, `nextProps.arr`) does not mean you have *two instances*.

When you mutate the array with push, you modify the instance. When `shouldComponentUpdate` runs it compares the references and because they point to the same instance, the array lengths are the same.

If you want to pass down a new array with different elements or properties, then you need to create a new array too.

It's quite easy to substitute `push` for `concat`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  self.setState({
    arr: self.state.concat([7])
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing the same array in your `if`, ie., you are modifying the same array instead of creating a new one and you're working two references to the same array in `shouldComponentUpdate`.

[You should always treat props and state as immutable](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html#mutating-props-is-bad) and therefore creating a new array with `.concat` instead of pushing onto the array in state will fix your current issue.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    this.setState({arr: this.state.concat([7])});
}.bind(this), 2000);
```

If you'd have done `this.props.arr === nextProps.arr` within `shouldComponentUpdate` you'd see that the arrays would be equal to each other.